# Ultra slow upload speeds with SSL

Tags: ssl, performance, wordpress

My wordpress website subdomain  upload.website.com  bypasses cloudflare.

Uploading to https://upload.website.com is extremely slow - 3 - 15 mins for 100mb

However I did some speed tests on the server and one speed test went really fast.

http://upload.website.com  without the HTTPS...... is FULL SPEED.

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: Deep packet inspection, perhaps? You should really give more contextual information. [Slow SSL is a myth that has been debunked](https://istlsfastyet.com).